# Setting Scroll on Slider Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am building a news feed with slides that show a summary and a read more button that when clicked reveals the rest of the content.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pbunz5ue/1/

When Read More is clicked the story opens and the scrolling stops, then the user clicks Less, its hides the story and continues scrolling.

When Read More is clicked I need the scroll of the div to be aligned so that the opened story starts at the top of the div. My slider does this perfectly the first round the stories make, once they are displayed a second time from the button up this no longer works.

Can someone explain why ??

Here is my code:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //User clicks Read More, add 'open' class to news item
    $('.news-read-more').on('click', function() {
        blockedSlider = true;
        clearInterval(myTimer);
        $('.news-list').children('li').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        });
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');

        var n = $(this).parent();
        var pos = n.position();
        $('.news-slider-wrapper').scrollTop(pos.top); 

    }); 

    //User clicks Less, remove 'open' class from news item
    $('.news-read-less').on('click', function() {
        if (blockedSlider == true) {
            blockedSlider = false;
            $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
            myTimer = setInterval(slideLoop, 2000)
        }
    });

    var myTimer = setInterval(slideLoop, 2000)
    var blockedSlider = false;

    function slideLoop() {
        //  Work out width of current slider size
        var widthPx = $('.news-list-item').css('height');
        var width = widthPx.substring(0, widthPx.length - 2);

        // Work out current left  
        var left = $('.news-list').css('top');
        left = left.substring(0, left.length - 2);


        if (left <= -(width * 2)) {
            var neg = '-' + widthPx;
            $('.news-list').css('top', neg);

            var slide = $('.news-list li:first');
            $('.news-list').children('li:first').remove();
            $('.news-list ').append(slide);

            //User clicks Read More, add 'open' class to news item
            $('.news-read-more').on('click', function() {
                blockedSlider = true;
                clearInterval(myTimer);
                $('.news-list').children('li').each(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                });
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');

                var n = $(this).parent();
                var pos = n.position();
                $('.news-slider-wrapper').scrollTop(pos.top - 360); 

            }); 

            //User clicks Less, remove 'open' class from news item
            $('.news-read-less').on('click', function() {
                if (blockedSlider == true) {
                    blockedSlider = false;
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
                    myTimer = setInterval(slideLoop, 2000)
                }
            });         

            var move = "-=" + widthPx;
            $('.news-list').animate({ top: move }, "slow", "swing");
        }
        else {
            var move = "-=" + widthPx;
            $('.news-list').animate({ top: move }, "slow", "swing");
        }
    }   

});
```

Comment: ... maybe the problem is caused by negative "top" position of `.news-list` that busts the position of the opened element.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by negative "top" position of .news-list that busts the position of the opened element.

-> I update your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pbunz5ue/3/ <-

#### What I've changed

1. the main error:

   when you calculate the position you've not considered the negative `top` offset of the news container `.news-list` when it slide up:

   I've changed this two lines:

   ```
   var pos = n.position();
   $('.news-slider-wrapper').scrollTop(pos.top);
   ```

   in:

   ```
   var pos = n.position().top + parseInt($(".news-list").css("top")) || n.position().top;
   $('.news-slider-wrapper').scrollTop(pos);
   ```

   If `$(".news-list")` has top position I add It to the calculation of position (if the result is `auto` there is a fallback that prevent `NaN` result `|| n.position().top`)
2. You had duplicated the handler `$('.news-read-more').on('click')` and `$('.news-read-less').on('click');` I deleted those within the function because they seems useless.

### EDIT:: .on click issue

Try this two way to solve your problem:

#### 1.

If you have some problem when new item was added into your list try to bind the event to the "items" container `.news-list` and filter the selector every time it will fire:

```
$('.news-read-more').on('click', function() { //...
$('.news-read-less').on('click', function() { //...
```

becomes:

```
$('.news-list').on('click','.news-read-more', function() { //...
$('.news-list').on('click','.news-read-less', function() { //...
```

the container `.news-list` never change during your animation, and DOM manipulation.

#### 2.

An other way is to change this rows, in your code:

```
 var slide = $('.news-list li:first');
 $('.news-list').children('li:first').remove();
 $('.news-list ').append(slide);
```

becomes:

```
 var slide = $('.news-list li:first');
 $('.news-list ').append(slide);
```

or:

```
 $('.news-list ').append('.news-list li:first');
```

if you `.remove` the element, (I think) you unbind all event because you remove the element from DOM, but you not need to remove you need to move it from top to bottom. This way prevent the unbind of `click` event.

---

I hope to had understand the problem :).

*sorry for may bad english*

Comment: Hi! The reason I had duplicated the functions is because otherwise the events are not binded to the Read More/Less buttons when the slide is appended to the end. If I look at your jsFiddle I see this is the case and I cant open any of my slides once they are appended

Comment: Ok. I edit my answer, but for me, in my fiddle, all works fine.